# Does the Dragon Reborn remember all of his past lives after The Gathering Storm?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

At the end of *The Gathering Storm*, the book implies that the Dragon, Rand al'Thor, can remember all of his past lives. Also, in the Prophecies of the Dragon it says "the many become one". Are there any references to other past lives, besides Lews Therin?

Comment: Well, I can think of at least one other that is mentioned in various books but why don't you finish the series first to avoid spoilers?

Comment: I did finish the series. Its 14 books. Where is one other memory mentioned?

Comment: Well in the last few books (sorry don't have them at hand, hence the comment) he mentions Arthur Hawkwind and it seems clear he remembers at least some things about that life.

Comment: You are misremembering. Artur Hawkwing is a different soul to The Dragon. That's why Hawkwing responded to the Horn in TGH, whilst Lews Therin didn't. Mat however does remember Hawkwings face - see Tuons prophecy about him.

Comment: There is a reference to a 3rd person by Lews Therin. This starts after Moridin and Rand should balefire at each other and they hit (moridin used the true power). The consensus on the dragonmount forum that this person is Moridin and this is what allowed the 'transfer'. I don't recall a reference to another life. I was expecting to see that after the Gathering Storm.

Comment: A good place to check would be his revelation on Dragonmount, because iirc that's when he realizes that the Dragon has always beaten the Dark One, contrary to what Ba'alzamon said at the beginning of the series.

Answer (score 5):

Early on in the series, one of the Forsaken (Ishamael?) told the Dragon that the Dragon hasn't won all of the fights against the Dark One.

At the end of the series, after his revelation at the Dragonmount, he repudiates this with the claim that he's won *every* battle against the Dark One. We presume that the only way he could have known that with certainty is that he remembers at least some component of each of his incarnations.

Comment: Not true. Maybe he deducts he has won all the battles, just because otherwise the DO would have destroyed the world and they wouldn't be there.

Comment: Not necessarily; Moiraine stated that it may not be that clear, and Ba'alzamon told him that he'd lost on occasion. He didn't learn anything new on the Dragonmount that would have let him reason out that Ba'alzamon was lying to him, but he did come to terms with his prior reincarnation. Given his mental state up to then and the fact that he immediately remembers other parts of being the Dragon, it seems highly likely that it was memory, not reason, that told him that.